Header file between projects in same solution not exporting functions
I have a solution in visual studio with 2 projects, 1 a C++ windows .lib library and the other a C++ Google Test project. The files in the library project are just two header files and two CPP files. One of the files was generated by visual studio, if I put functions in there then it works in the Google Test project, however I created another header file however any functions I put in there don't work in the google test project, however if I define variables in that header it does work.

Header files typically only declare functions, b ut doesn't define (implement) them. You need to link with the libraries or object files that do define (implement) the functions.

yeah i did define the function in the cpp file and I added the lib file to the linker

Did you also add the new file to the linking of the library? And is the file type of the "cpp" file "source" (sometimes when you first add a header file and then rename it visual studio gets confused). Also describe the EXACT problem you see when linking your unit tests.

The executable project needs a reference to the library project. See Add a reference

there is a reference and the cpp type is c/c++ code,  and the function just doesnt appear at all. like it just doesnt show up

You need to show us the actual code you are using that cause the error . As it stands we can only guess what may be wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

there is no "error", its literally just not showing the function

It turns out the projects were on different versions of C++ and that causes the functions to not show up anywhere.
I fixed it by setting them to the same version (latest)
